# Elementary Combinatorics Problem

Tags: combinatorics

I am having trouble with the following, probably missing something obvious:

Prove that $\displaystyle {{nQ^{\frac{1}{n}}+n}\choose{n}}>{Q} \,\,\,\forall n\geq2, Q\in{\mathbb{Z}^+}$.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is $Q$ here?

Comment: $Q$ had better be taken as $Q>0$ otherwise the fractional power might give problems

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify. $Q$ is a positive integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof by induction, starting at $n=2$:

Basis:
$$
\binom{2\sqrt{Q}+2}{2} = \frac12\left( 2\sqrt{Q}+2\right)\left( 2\sqrt{Q}+1\right)= \left( \sqrt{Q}+1\right)\left( 2\sqrt{Q}+1\right)> 2Q>Q
$$
Induction:  Assume $\binom{(n-1)\sqrt[n-1]{Q}+n-1}{n-1}> Q$. Then 
$$\binom{n\sqrt[n]{Q}+n}{n} =  \binom{n\sqrt[n]{Q}+n-1}{n-1} \frac{n\sqrt[n]{Q}+n}{n}> \binom{n\sqrt[n]{Q}+n-1}{n-1}> \binom{(n-1)\sqrt[n]{Q}+n-1}{n-1}>Q$$

Comment: Why is there a $\sqrt[n]{Q}$ instead of $\sqrt[n-1]{Q}$ in $\binom{(n-1)\sqrt[n]{Q}+n-1}{n-1}>Q$?